# The error shows The column name 2015-2016 was not found in this resultset

Tags: java

I'm Wondering what could be the possible error in this code. I'm trying to display a data in the text box from the search query. It  seems there's been a problem in the Result set.

```js
if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
  if (txtsearch.getText().isEmpty()) {
    txtaccountnumber.setText(null);
    txtfirstname.setText(null);
    txtmiddlename.setText(null);
    txtlastname.setText(null);
    cbgender.setSelectedIndex(0);
    txtage.setText(null);
    txtdateofbirth.setText(null);
    txtplaceofbirth.setText(null);
    txtaddress.setText(null);
    txtnameofguardian.setText(null);
    txtoccupation.setText(null);
    txtaddressofguardian.setText(null);
    txtstudentfatherfirstname.setText(null);
    txtstudentfathermiddlename.setText(null);
    txtstudentfatherlastname.setText(null);
    txtstudentmotherfirstname.setText(null);
    txtstudentmothermiddlename.setText(null);
    txtstudentmotherlastname.setText(null);
    txtreligion.setText(null);
    txttribe.setText(null);
    txtcitizenship.setText(null);
    txtelementary.setText(null);
    txtintermediate.setText(null);
    txtgrade7.setText(null);
    cbgrade7schoolyear.setSelectedIndex(0);
    txtgrade8.setText(null);
    cbgrade8schoolyear.setSelectedIndex(0);
    txtgrade9.setText(null);
    cbgrade9schoolyear.setSelectedIndex(0);
    txtgrade10.setText(null);
    cbgrade10schoolyear.setSelectedIndex(0);
    txtgrade11.setText(null);
    cbgrade11schoolyear.setSelectedIndex(0);
    txtgrade12.setText(null);
    cbgrade12schoolyear.setSelectedIndex(0);

  } else {
    try {
      conn = mycon.con;
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from student where studfirst like'" + txtsearch.getText().toUpperCase() + "'");

      while (rs.next()) {
        txtaccountnumber.setText(rs.getString(1));
        txtfirstname.setText(rs.getString(2));
        txtmiddlename.setText(rs.getString(3));
        txtlastname.setText(rs.getString(4));
        cbgender.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(5));
        txtage.setText(rs.getString(6));
        txtplaceofbirth.setText(rs.getString(7));
        txtdateofbirth.setText(rs.getString(8));
        txtaddress.setText(rs.getString(9));
        txtnameofguardian.setText(rs.getString(10));
        txtoccupation.setText(rs.getString(11));
        txtaddressofguardian.setText(rs.getString(12));
        txtstudentfatherfirstname.setText(rs.getString(13));
        txtstudentfathermiddlename.setText(rs.getString(14));
        txtstudentfatherlastname.setText(rs.getString(15));
        txtstudentmotherfirstname.setText(rs.getString(16));
        txtstudentmothermiddlename.setText(rs.getString(17));
        txtstudentmotherlastname.setText(rs.getString(18));
        txtreligion.setText(rs.getString(19));
        txttribe.setText(rs.getString(20));
        txtcitizenship.setText(rs.getString(21));
        txtelementary.setText(rs.getString(22));
        txtintermediate.setText(rs.getString(23));
        txtgrade7.setText(rs.getString(24));
        cbgrade7schoolyear.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(25));
        txtgrade8.setText(rs.getString(26));
        cbgrade8schoolyear.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(27));
        txtgrade9.setText(rs.getString(28));
        cbgrade9schoolyear.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(29));
        txtgrade10.setText(rs.getString(30));
        cbgrade10schoolyear.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(rs.getString(31)));
        txtgrade11.setText(rs.getString(32));
        cbgrade11schoolyear.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(33));
        txtgrade12.setText(rs.getString(34));
        cbgrade12schoolyear.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(35));

      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error" + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
}

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

  // TODO add your handling code here:
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    try {
      conn = mycon.con;
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from student where studfirst like'" + txtfirstname.getText().toUpperCase() + "' or
 studmiddle like'" + txtmiddlename.getText().toUpperCase() + "%' or
 stud_last like'" + txtlastname.getText().toUpperCase() + "%' or
 accountnumber like'" + txtaccountnumber.getText().toUpperCase());

      while (rs.next()) {
        txtaccountnumber.setText(rs.getString(1));
        txtfirstname.setText(rs.getString(2));
        txtmiddlename.setText(rs.getString(3));
        txtlastname.setText(rs.getString(4));
        cbgender.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(5));
        txtage.setText(rs.getString(6));
        txtplaceofbirth.setText(rs.getString(7));
        txtdateofbirth.setText(rs.getString(8));
        txtaddress.setText(rs.getString(9));
        txtnameofguardian.setText(rs.getString(10));
        txtoccupation.setText(rs.getString(11));
        txtaddressofguardian.setText(rs.getString(12));
        txtstudentfatherfirstname.setText(rs.getString(13));
        txtstudentfathermiddlename.setText(rs.getString(14));
        txtstudentfatherlastname.setText(rs.getString(15));
        txtstudentmotherfirstname.setText(rs.getString(16));
        txtstudentmothermiddlename.setText(rs.getString(17));
        txtstudentmotherlastname.setText(rs.getString(18));
        txtreligion.setText(rs.getString(19));
        txttribe.setText(rs.getString(20));
        txtcitizenship.setText(rs.getString(21));
        txtelementary.setText(rs.getString(22));
        txtintermediate.setText(rs.getString(23));
        txtgrade7.setText(rs.getString(24));
        cbgrade7schoolyear.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(25));
        txtgrade8.setText(rs.getString(26));
        cbgrade8schoolyear.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(27));
        txtgrade9.setText(rs.getString(28));
        cbgrade9schoolyear.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(29));
        txtgrade10.setText(rs.getString(30));
        cbgrade10schoolyear.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(rs.getString(31)));
        txtgrade11.setText(rs.getString(32));
        cbgrade11schoolyear.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(33));
        txtgrade12.setText(rs.getString(34));
        cbgrade12schoolyear.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(35));
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and [mcve] - what is this code? It is not jQuery and it is not pure JavaScript - it looks like some mix of JAVA and JavaScript. Please fix that

Comment: What error do you get? Also that code is awful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clarify the error what do you get. Apart from that what I can see is issue with sql query part.

First thing you must use `PreparedStatement` when you have to deal with dynamic or runtime parameters.

Change this below code:

```
stmt.executeQuery("select * from student where studfirst like'" + txtsearch.getText().toUpperCase() + "'");
```

As this:

```
String sql="select * from student where studfirst like '?'";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1,txtsearch.getText().toUpperCase());
rs=ps.executeQuery();
```

Also you need to rectify the below query, BTW, you cannot break lines as you done in the below query.

```
"select * from student where studfirst like'" + txtfirstname.getText().toUpperCase() + "' or
 studmiddle like'" + txtmiddlename.getText().toUpperCase() + "%' or
 stud_last like'" + txtlastname.getText().toUpperCase() + "%' or
 accountnumber like'" + txtaccountnumber.getText().toUpperCase());
```

Must be some what like this:

```
String sql="select * from student where studfirst like '?' or studmiddle like '?%' or stud_last like'?%' or accountnumber like '?'";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1,txtsearch.getText().toUpperCase());
ps.setString(2,txtlastname.getText().toUpperCase());
ps.setString(3,txtaccountnumber.getText().toUpperCase());
rs=ps.executeQuery();
```